# Save error :field is not writeable

Tags: apex, trigger

Could you please suggest me why i am receiving this error? I am  moving  listprice of backup object to listprice of opportunityline item. Both  have same datatype (currency(16,2).

oli.ListPrice = lp.listprice__c;

```
trigger lockproduct on lockproduct__c (after insert, after update, before insert, before update) {

     List<lockproduct__C> lplist = new list<lockproduct__C>();
    for(lockproduct__C lp :Trigger.new){
            Product2 pt = [Select p.Name, p.Id From Product2 p where p.Id= :lp.Product__c];
              if(Trigger.isafter && lp.lockrecord__c  = false){
              opportunitylineitem oli = new opportunitylineitem();
          //      oli.Name = pt.name;

              oli.ListPrice = lp.listprice__c; 
              oli.Opportunity = lp.opportunityid;
              oli.Product2    = pt.id; 
              oli.salesprice__c = lp.UnitPrice;

              oli.unit_quantity__c =  lp.Unit_Quantity__c;
               insert oli;
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the List Price comes from the Pricebook Entry

> Corresponds to the UnitPrice on the PricebookEntry that is associated
>   with this line item, which can be in the standard pricebook or a
>   custom pricebook. A client application can use this information to
>   show whether the unit price (or sales price) of the line item differs
>   from the pricebook entry list price

Docs are helpful at times and the information is easily available whenever you need it

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I am facing same issue for product  filed too. Could you please provide some solution  to move  value to these fields through trigger?  I need to insert  opportunity line item record form shadow object to opportunity once it get approved.